# SQLite issues on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an application that saves its data in a sqlite database accessed through SQLiteOpenHelper. It works fine on all mobile phone and other tablets except Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 (10.1). Other activities that do not require database access are working fine on the Samsung tab, the exception is raised while trying to access the database. Is there a different way of manipulating database for Samsung Galaxy Tab? Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the exception that is raised? Please edit and add the details to your question.

Comment: did u found solution ? im also facing same issue